# Address formatting

Tags: contacts, import, forms, addresses, data-import

I'm trying to find a way to change the address format in CiviCRM, to the Australian address format. I've had a good search but can only find this these from 5 years ago.

https://civicrm.org/blog/erikhommel/street-parsing

I want to be able to have the items in separate fields when importing and adding contacts. Eg:

{apartment or unit} {street number} 
{street name} {street type} 
{city} {state} {postal code} {country}

Here is an example if that helps. https://www.imgur.com/a/ZhWVtAD

Any advice would be appreciated.

Kind Regards Scott

Comment: it may help folk help you if you explain why you need the address splitting to that extent

Comment: Please add your CiviCRM version to the question text (and add the appropriate tag)

Answer (score 1):

To enable CiviCRM storing in separate addres fields you have to tick the box for Steet Address Parsing in Administer>Localization>Address Settings. I do not know for certain if this will allow you to import into separate fields but I would expect so.

If you want your own specific format or additional fields you will have to make changes in the code, here is an (old) example: https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.streetformatnl

Comment: Yeah that's not it unfortunately. Dosen't change the fields. Anyone else know or other support options I can try?

Comment: Yes, you can develop your own solution based on this. There is no other option AFAIK

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [l10naddress](https://github.com/MegaphoneJon/com.megaphonetech.addressl10n) extension by Megaphone Tech which appears to be aimed specifically at meeting this need for regionalised address formats.

Comment: Thanks for the plug! However, I don't think the extension will help here.  It really only helps if you do international mailings and need to set the address format for each country differently. The OP needs street address parsing - I think Erik's answer is correct and I'm not sure why it's not working.